# Convert Exif date to different format

Tags: rest, datetime

I am getting an exif date value like

```
EXIFPhotoDate: 1506173228000 and
UploadDate: 1506485214000
```

but I know it is

```
EXIFPhotoDate   23/9/2017, 23:27 and 
UploadDate  9/27/2017, 01:59
```

The former is when queried via REST and the latter is when queried via the table.

How can I get standard date/time from a value like this?

Comment: Tell us at least what language you are using.

Comment: thanks @CássioMazzochiMolin I have updated the question based on the new understanding you gave me. Any help will be greatly appreciated as this is for assisting in the Hurricane operations.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin Sorry put it back I will accept it and ask a new question now. I gave you credit for your reply in the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a number of milliseconds since January 01 1970 in UTC. If you remove the `000` from the end, you will have a [Unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com), that is, the number of seconds since January 01 1970 in UTC:

```
unixTimestamp = 1506173228000 / 1000
```

Once your question doesn't state any programming language, it's hard to give you further help.

Comment: Thanks - it's not a language specific question. I am working on some data from the disaster in Peurto Rico and we have got data with this time stamp and need to convert it to dd/mm/yyyy and hh:mm (24h clock) - is this possible via a formula in excel? or if necessary python.

Comment: @GeorgeC You could use `=(((<cell-id-here>/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)` for seconds or `=((((<cell-id-here>/60)/60)/24)/1000)+DATE(1970,1,1)` for milliseconds. Then format the cell as date. Just keep in mind that the result date/time will be in UTC.

Comment: @GeorgeC If you know the timezone offset, you can use `-TIME(hour-offset-here,0,0)` or `+TIME(<hour-offset-here>,0,0)` in the end of the above mentioned formula: `=((((<cell-id-here>/60)/60)/24)/1000)+DATE(1970,1,1)+TIME(<hour-offset-here>,0,0)`.