# Import data from REST service in Google Sheet

Tags: python, excel, rest, google-sheets

I want to just get one line from a rest url in google sheets.

When I try

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://imageryuploader.geoplatform.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ImageEvents/MapServer/1/query?text=A0016-4646&outFields=EXIFPhotoDate")
```

I get the whole code block for the page

I get NA for `=IMPORTHTML("https://imageryuploader.geoplatform.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ImageEvents/MapServer/1/query?text=A0016-4646&outFields=EXIFPhotoDate", "list",1)`

If I just put `https://imageryuploader.geoplatform.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ImageEvents/MapServer/1/query?text=A0016-4646&outFields=EXIFPhotoDate`
 into a browser I get

> ## records: 2
>
> EXIFPhotoDate: 1506173228000 Point: X: -66.61147999999997  Y:
>   18.279028333000042
>
> EXIFPhotoDate: 1506173228000 Point: X: -66.61147999999997  Y:
>   18.279028333000042

I want to create a google sheet where we have

column A -the image name, 
and in column B it uses =IMPORTHTML("https://imageryuploader.geoplatform.gov/arcgis/rest/services/ImageEvents/MapServer/1/query?text=A0016-4646&outFields=EXIFPhotoDate", "list",1) or something similar and gets the UNIX D/T. 
Finally, in column C it should put in the dd/mm/yyyy and in D the 24 UTC time.

Thanks to [Convert Exif date to different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559935/convert-exif-date-to-different-format) I have the formula for converting the unix d/t.

If Google Sheets can't do it, happy to use EXCEL or Python 2.7

Sample GSheet is at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ff-gohRIkumpxqSeEVKyGq6PPEP542PJSB1vBIzI1jA/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed or used the google sheets API? 
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

There is some sample code provided.

Here is the GitHub link 
https://github.com/kurtlocker/sheets-api

Hope it helps.